# Random number generator not printing numbers correctly

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript program is supposed to print out random numbers, between two max and min values given by the user. It works great with pre-input numbers, but as soon as I introduce the prompts to get max and min, the numbers start printing out funny.

```
var min, max, hmany, i;
var n, w, ans, rsp;


min = prompt("Minimum number for addition problems");
//console.log(min);
max = prompt("Maximum number for addition problems");
//console.log(max);
hmany = prompt("How many questions do you want to answer?");

 for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
     n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
     console.log(n);
   }
```

Sample Output:(when given 1 for min and 10 for max)

```
21
61
71
51
41
01
01
11
21
11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, you're doing operations on strings. And when the min is "1", what you do is

```
n = someOperation + "1",
```

which gives a string ending in `"1"`.

You have to parse the strings to numbers :

```
min = parseFloat(prompt("Minimum number for addition problems"));
```

Comment: @AustinDonley Is there a reason why you didn't accept the answer ? Something missing ?

Comment: Only forgot. Couldn't until it was 15 minutes old at the time. And forgot. It worked great.